# How to get Request Headers?

Tags: javascript, request, xmlhttprequest

How to get request headers through javascript in console
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)

Comment: There is no request response, but I need to get Request Headers